# Загрузка файлов с разных серверов

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть ios приложение написанное на swift. В нем происходит загрузка файлов с сервера по прямым ссылкам.

Но если, например, с сервером что-то случилось и я перешёл на другой. Могу ли я заменить ссылки в приложении не обновляя его через AppStoreConnect?

Может быть это можно сделать через push-notifications или как-то ещё?

Comment: Текст, который является исходным кодом Вашего приложения Вы в праве обновлять только через App Store Connect.

Comment: Нет необходимости менять ссылки, достаточно менять IP-адреса у доменов, которые используются в ссылках